# Rotate, not orbit, the view?

Tags: interface

I'm doing some sculpting in a first-person type of view. I'd like to rotate the camera, as opposed to orbiting the focus point, or rotating the world. I've searched, and gone as far as editing the bindings, but despite the name of  `bpy.ops.view3d.rotate`, that just orbits, like `bpy.ops.view3d.view_orbit`. Is it possible to rotate the view camera in a first-person style?

Comment: Double tap R with the camera selected

Answer (score 2):

Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd> to enter Walk/Fly mode and you can then use the mouse to 'look around'. Pressing <kbd>W</kbd><kbd>S</kbd><kbd>A</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> moves Forward, Backward, Left, Right. <kbd>LShift</kbd> for 'fast' mode, other keys listed in the status bar at the bottom of the window. <kbd>Esc</kbd> to exit Walk/Fly mode. You can choose Walk/Fly from the View/Navigation menu.

Comment: In 2023 it appears that the shortcut to get into walk/fly mode is SHIFT - `
https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/navigate/walk_fly.html

Answer (score 0):

I personally would parent my camera to an empty that sits in a comfortable target distance out in the center of my view.

I would then change my view mode to **View**, by using <kbd>Alt</kbd>  + <kbd>Spacebar</kbd> >> <kbd>V</kbd>.

I would make sure to set my pivot point to be at the median of my selection by using <kbd>,</kbd>.

I would make my camera empty the active object, and control it in the following ways:

---

To move around in freestyle like 1st person:

<kbd>G</kbd> >> <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> >> Move the mouse.

To Strafe, grab the X arrow on the translate wiget, and move it left or right.

To Change my elevation grab the Y arrow on the translate widget.

To orbit <kbd>G</kbd> >> <kbd>Z</kbd> >> move the mouse around.